# Localization of a ring at a prime ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, soft-question

I have a general (maybe a bit philosophical) about some kind of ring theoretical 
argumentation method. 
In commutative algebra there is often used the 
method of localizing a Ring $R$ at it´s prime ideal to $R_p$. The way
of realization is clear to me but not whole spectrum of it's usage.

The only one that I seen was that
there exist a theorem that if we have a inclusion of affine schemes it's
enough to prove the proper equality of both at stalks 
(which are in this case the localisations at prime ideals). 
Futhermore often in literature in some ring theoretical theorems some 
properties are called "local" so that "it would be enough to asump that
the ring is localized". Can anybody explain the background of 
this often used "reduction step"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ring theory, a property is called "local", if it holds for the ring if and only if it holds for every localization. In fact, it often looks like this:

> For a ring $R$ and a property $P$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. Property $P$ holds for $R$.
> 2. Property $P$ holds for every $R_p$, where $p \leq R$ is a prime ideal.
> 3. Property $P$ holds for every $R_m$, where $m \leq R$ is a maximal ideal.

Furthermore, we can make the same construction for a module:

> For a ring $R$, an $R$-module $M$ and a property $P$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. Property $P$ holds for $M$.
> 2. Property $P$ holds for every $M_p$, where $p \leq R$ is a prime ideal.
> 3. Property $P$ holds for every $M_m$, where $m \leq R$ is a maximal ideal.

Here, $M_p := R_p \otimes M$. One of the most important local properties of a module is being the zero module, as many other properties can be reduced to that one.

The reason to care about such theorems is that many problems and computations are easier over local rings.